# Securing a workspace variable

Tags: security, variables, matlab, history, workspace

Maybe you have come past the following situation. You're working and you start to run one script after another and then suddenly realize you've changed the value of a variable you are interested in. Apart from making a backup of the workspace, is there no other way to protect the variables?

Is there a way to select individual variables in the workspace that you're going to protect?

Apart from seeing the command history register, is there a history register of the different values that have been given to one particular variable?

Answer (score 9):

Running scripts in sequence is a recipe for disaster.  If possible, try turning those scripts into functions.  This will naturally do away with the problems of overwriting variables you are running into, since variables inside functions are local to those functions whereas variables in scripts are local to the workspace -- and thus easily accessed/overwritten by separate scripts (often unintentionally, especially if you use variable names like "result").

Comment: +1. Definitely learn to write functions rather than scripts. This makes your code more flexible, more useful for the future.

Comment: +1. Technical nitpick: variables in scripts are also local; they are just local to the "base" workspace, which persists for the life of the Matlab session, and which all scripts run in. Global variables are declared with the "global" keyword and can be accessed from any workspace which declares them.

Comment: So you're telling me that a good programmer in Matlab all that he does is done through functions?
If every time I wanna do something I have to make a function that is not going to be more tedious and less flexible?

Comment: RE: Peterstone's comment - No, that is not what I'm saying.  Sometimes a script is more appropriate than a function.  But if you are running into the problem mentioned by the OP, that means whatever you are doing is probably best done with functions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no workspace history. I would say, if you run into that problem that you described, you should consider changing your programming style.

I would suggest you:

1. put that much code or information in your script, so you can start from an empty workspace to fulfill a task. For that reason I always put `clear all` at the start of my main file.
2. If it's getting too complex, consider calling functions. If you need values that are generated by another script or function, rewrite that script to become a function and call it in your main file or save the variables. Loading variables is absolutely okay. But running scripts in sequence leads to disaster as [mentioned by marciovm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212678/matlab-securing-a-workspace-variable/4213010#4213010).

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that writing functions can be helpful in this situation.  If however you are manipulating very large data sets then you need to be careful to write your code in a form which doesn't make multiple copies of variables within your functions or you may run into memory shortage problems.